# How to clone Ubuntu 18.04 partition from a notebook SSD to a desktop PC SSD?

Tags: partitioning, backup, clone

I'd like to clone my Ubuntu partition (on the SSD of my notebook (250GB)) on a new SSD (250GB) which I'd like to install on my desktop PC.
This is because I'd like to use my desktop PC which is much more powerful, and avoid to reinstall the whole working environment.

The notebook SSD currently has 2 partitions: one with Windows 10 (150GB) and the other with Ubuntu 18.04 (100GB).

I need to clone/backup only the ubuntu partion on the new SSD.

Is it possible to clone only the ubuntu partition and make the disk bootable?

Alternatively can I install ubuntu from scratch on the new ssd and then copying in some way the notebook ubuntu partition preserving the operation of the system?
Which programs-tools I could use?

I have an USB 3.0-SATA adapter if it is necessary.

Thank you so much.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS system? Are both the same and is Ubuntu install booting in UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you have gpt partitioning and you cannot easily clone just one partition. With gpt, the partition GUID is in the partition, the primary partition table & the backup partition table. I almost always suggest new install & restore from your normal backup to prove your backups are complete. Most configuration settings are in /home. Best to also export list of installed apps & use that to reinstall them. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Try your notebook SSD in your desktop, if that works, clone your notebook SSD to your Desktop SSD and then remove the unwanted Windows partition. dd is the most direct way to clone a disk. **sudo dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy**. Use caution with dd.

Comment: Another alternative is to do a fresh install on the desktop SSD and then copy your notebook home directory to your desktop using **rsync**, (or **grsync** if you prefer a GUI). Then reinstall any useful programs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I think I'll use the dd or the rsync command.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer your question but I am no expert on this. Recently I discovered something amazing. I took my hard drive out of my desktop computer, running an ASUS motherboard with an I7 processor and was curious to see what would happen if I put it into a Sony Vaio laptop with a core duo CPU. I was amazed to discover that the installation booted with absolutely no problems whatsoever. Maybe it was just a fluke but somehow I dont think so. I was running xubuntu 18.04. See what happens if you try to boot off that partition in the other machine. Then, if it does boot, I would suggest cloning the partition with clonezilla, and restoring it to the computer you want to boot off. I am fairly convinced it will work but I know for a fact you cannot do that with windows. Since you are only going to be using the ubuntu installation it is worth a try

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot take out the notebook ssd: I have to leave my notebook working.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had time to do this operation.
I installed ubuntu from scratch on the new SSD (on a 100GB partition), then I used grsync to copy my /home folder on a pendrive and then on my new SSD.
At the end I had to install some packages but it worked.
Thank you so much for your support. :)